# :highest_rated scope to order by average rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a `Product` and each product has_many `ratings`. I'm trying to create a `:highest_rated` Product scope which orders the products by their highest average rating (each rating is in the `ratings` table). I tried this:

```
scope :highest_rated, includes(:ratings).order('avg(ratings.rating) DESC')
```

But that gave me a `misuse of aggregate: avg()` error.

Any tips on how to order my products by their highest average rating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
scope :highest_rated, includes(:ratings).group('product_id').order('AVG(ratings.rating) DESC')
```

To only fetch the products with an existing rating:

```
scope :highest_rated, includes(:ratings).group('product_id').where('ratings.rating IS NOT NULL').order('AVG(ratings.rating) DESC')
```

EDIT: the above won't work in PostgreSQL. I used this instead (which works in both SQLite and PostgreSQL):

```
scope :highest_rated, where("products.id in (select product_id from ratings)").group('products.id, products.name, products.all_other_fields').joins(:ratings).order('AVG(ratings.rating) DESC')
```