# Active Record: find records by ceratin condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My goal is to find three doctors with more than 1 review and with average rating >= 4

At the moment I'm using this service

```
class RatingCounterService
  def get_three_best_doctors
    doctors = find_doctors_with_reviews
    sorted_doctors = sort_doctors(doctors)
    reversed_hash = reverse_hash_with_sorted_doctors(sorted_doctors)
    three_doctors = get_first_three_doctors(reversed_hash)
  end

  private

  def find_doctors_with_reviews
    doctors_with_reviews = {}

    Doctor.all.each do |doctor|
      if doctor.reviews.count > 0 && doctor.average_rating >= 4
        doctors_with_reviews[doctor] = doctor.average_rating
      end
    end

    doctors_with_reviews
  end

  def sort_doctors(doctors)
    doctors.sort_by { |doctor, rating| rating }
  end

  def reverse_hash_with_sorted_doctors(sorted_doctors)
    reversed = sorted_doctors.reverse_each.to_h
  end

  def get_first_three_doctors(reversed_hash)
    reversed_hash.first(3).to_h.keys
  end
end
```

Which is very slow.

My Doctor model:

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  def average_rating
    reviews.count == 0 ? 0 : reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
  end
end
```

Review model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor

  validates :rating, presence: true
end
```

I can find all doctors with more than 1 review with this request

```
doctors_with_reviews = Doctor.joins(:reviews).group('doctors.id').having('count(doctors.id) > 0')
```

But how can I find doctors with an average rating >= 4 and order them by the highest rating if the "average rating" is an instance method?

Comment: In order to find **"with 1 or more"** review, **all** you need to do is `Doctor.joins(:reviews)`. In order to find **"with more than 1"** (which is what you wrote), you'd actually need to do `Doctor.joins(:reviews).group('doctors.id').having('count(doctors.id) > 1')`.

Comment: `But how can I find doctors with an average rating >= 4 and order them by the highest rating if the "average rating" is an instance method?`                                                                                          
 you can simply try `Doctor.includes(:reviews).where("reviews.avarage(:rating).round(2) >= ?", 4).group('doctors.id').having('count(doctors.id) > 0')` or create a scope on all above  and use the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this answer [:highest_rated scope to order by average rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641631/highest-rated-scope-to-order-by-average-rating?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My final solution is

```
Doctor.joins(:reviews).group('doctors.id').order('AVG(reviews.rating) DESC').limit(3)
```